# Search for two queries when getting multiple documents from a firestore collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have

```
  let dbREF = db
    .collection("Users")
    .doc("mQ4lxHU1sQhKlSmYYkik5F4dapz1")
    .collection("listings");
```

and I have

```
 dbREF
    .where("state", "==", uState)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
```

and I am basically getting multiple documents form the collection dbREF that match up with the .where state === uState. What I am trying to figure out is how I can search for two queries.

I tried doing this

```
 dbREF
    .where("state", "==", uState && "make", "==", selectedMake)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
```

But that did not work. I want to not only look for state with a value of uState but also make with a value of selectedMake. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction on how to do this. Thanks so much =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `where` multiple times, and the conditions will be AND'ed together. So:

```
 dbREF
    .where("state", "==", uState)
    .where("make", "==", selectedMake)
    .get()
```

Also see the Firebase documentation section on [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).